# Remote login using curl on cakephp returns blackhole

Tags: php, security, cakephp, authentication, curl

I have a website which i need to implement a login form to other website , which is based on cakephp.
I don't want to change the current security settings on the Cakephp website.
The login is based on the auth component.

Therefore I've pulled the form from the cakephp site using Curl, to keep the token fields.
When i login, i've got a blackhole message 'The request has been black-holed'.

How can i fix that without lowering the security level?
What are the steps to debug this situation.

Thanks

```
$url = WEB_APP . '/users/login';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$markup = strip_tags($result, '<form><input>');
echo $markup;
```

I've checked and the problem is that the cookie is missing , for sure.
I tried to use sendcookie on the cookie file i got from curl, and it's saved encoded. 
Using setrawcookie returns false. 
How can I set the cookie correctly?

Comment: You need to use the same session - i.e. use `-cookie-jar`. If you want more help you need to show what you're currently trying and the response.

Comment: I've checked and the problem is that the cookie is missing , for sure.
I tried to use sendcookie on the cookie file i got from curl, and it's  saved encoded.
Using setrawcookie returns false.
How can I set the cookie correctly?

Comment: Add your last comment as an edit to your question, since it adds debugging info and basically changes your question to something more specific.

Comment: any answer for this ?? I am facing the same issue.